# Edge-Core selective QinQ and tagged vlans

Tags: vlan, trunk

I'm trying to pack some vlans with selective QinQ. I need to inject VID 19,18 to VID 15.

```
#Port facing SP
interface ethernet 1/18
 switchport allowed vlan add 15 tagged
 switchport dot1q-tunnel mode uplink
 description Dot1Q-OneVlan

# Switch Uplink Port    
interface ethernet 1/11
 switchport allowed vlan add 15,19,18 untagged
 switchport dot1q-tunnel mode access
 switchport dot1q-tunnel service 15 match cvid 19
 switchport dot1q-tunnel service 15 match cvid 18
 description Pure-Tagged-VLAN
```

All QinQ works good but I have some vlans that I don't need to inject to 15.
For example I want to have VID 100 on port 1/11 to send traffic to my access client port 1/2.

How to pack vlans 19,18 to 15 and forward vlan 100,200 untouched?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on Network Engineering.

Comment: Can you please point me (maybe link) where it is?
P.S. Oh I've found it. Thanks ;)

Comment: @RonTrunk They marked that such questions is off topic there. Strange idea  to mark as offtopic if someone can't reply (( Looks like this is correct place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe somebody will face with problem. So to configure correctly add only two lines at port 1/11 config:

```
switchport allowed vlan add 100 tagged 
switchport dot1q-tun﻿nel service 100 match cvid 100 remove-ctag
```

This is very model specific, works on 4100 but not on 3628.